# setInterval stopping by itself when adding new items to the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, setinterval

I'm trying to create a new object, which will run asynchronously from the start and upon creation, the object will be pushed into an array. Whenever I add a new object by clicking the button, any other setInterval of the objects in the array stop. Then upon adding another one, all of them start again. What's going on here?

Here are the pieces of the code:

```
floor = {
    w_house: function() {
        this.shop = 'w_house';
        this.villains = [];
        this.thieves = 0;   
        that = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            if(that.thieves > 0) {
                console.log(that.thieves);
            }
        }, 10);
        lair.push(this);
        return $('<li/>').addClass('w_house').addClass('floor').append($('<div/>').addClass('test').text('test'));
}}

lair = [];

$('.button').live('click', function() {
        $('#lair ul').append(new floor[$(this).attr('id')]());
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. It is not safe to pass around this in constructor (on some browsers):

```
floor = {
    w_house: function() {
      this.shop = 'w_house';
      this.villains = [];
      this.thieves = 0;
      this.init = function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if(this.thieves > 0) {
                console.log(this.thieves);
            }
        }, 10);
        lair.push(this);
        return $('<li/>').addClass('w_house').addClass('floor').append($('<div/>').addClass('test').text('test'));
      }; 
}}

lair = [];

$('.button').live('click', function() {
      var floor_house = new floor[$(this).attr('id')]();
      $('#lair ul').append(floor_house.init());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and quick reply. But it has't worked :(

Comment: Are symptoms still the same?

Comment: Yes. EDIT: It seems only setTimeout of the last item is working. The previous ones are being cancelled as soon as a new one is pushed in.

Comment: I've just noticed something. When I console lair[1], lair[2] after adding a few, I don't see the this.init function.

Comment: I already fixed: that = this problem in the code I supplied you.

Comment: Ah sorry >.< I didn't notice it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown where you increment `thieves` member of your objects, but your `that` variable has global scope, every function execution overwrites its value. Try:

```
var that = this;
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD! THANK YOU!!!!! EDIT: I knew it was a problem with a global. Why else would it clear.